# Selling a Rented Apartment for Pesach

Tags: passover, selling-mechirat-chametz

There is a common practice of selling one's Chometz for Pesach. Some even sell a room or a specific area of their apartment for Pesach.

Let's say I was living in a rented apartment. Am I allowed to sell the entire apartment for Pesach to the Goy? Or is it better to limit the sale to a couple rooms?

Is this allowed? And if yes, are there more preferably Halachic scenarios that one should pursue?

Answer (score 2):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 114:5 -  [סימן קיד - דיני מכירת חמץ](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0113_L2) - says:

> **סעיף ה'**:
> אִם הַבַּיִת הוּא אֵצֶל הַיִשְֹרָאֵל רַק **בִּשְׂכִירוּת מִיִשְֹרָאֵל אַחֵר**, אֲזַי אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְהַשְׂכִּירוֹ לְאֵינוֹ יְהוּדִי לְבֵית דִּירָה בְּלִי רְשׁוּת הַמַּשְׂכִּיר, לָכֵן יַתְנֶה בְּפֵרוּשׁ עִם הָאֵינוֹ יְהוּדִי שֶׁאֵינוֹ מַשְׂכִּירוֹ לוֹ לָדוּר בּוֹ, רַק לְהַחְזִיק בּוֹ כֵּלָיו וּמִטַּלְטְלָיו, אֲבָל לֹא יַשְׂכִּירוֹ בְּפֵרוּשׁ לְהַחְזִיק בּוֹ אֶת הֶחָמֵץ, רַק סְתָם לְהַחְזִיק בּוֹ כֵּלָיו וּמִטַּלְטְלָיו כִּרְצוֹנוֹ. וּמִכָּל מָקוֹם **אִם הַמַּשְׂכִּיר בָּעִיר**, יִקַּח מִמֶּנּוּ רְשׁוּת לְהַשְׂכִּירוֹ, וְכֵן מִי שֶׁנּוֹסֵעַ לַדֶּרֶךְ קֹדֶם פֶּסַח, וְאִשְׁתּוֹ תִּמְכֹּר אֶת הֶחָמֵץ, יִתֵּן לָהּ רְשׁוּת בְּפֵרוּשׁ שֶׁתַּשְׂכִּיר אֶת הַחֶדֶר (תמ"ח ת"ג). ‏

If you're living in an apartment rented from a Jew,  then you cannot rent it to a non-Jew without permissions.

The solution is to rent it to the non-Jew for the purpose of storing items (but not to specify Chametz).

Better yet would be to get permission from the landlord.

The Kitzur doesn't mention anything about a non-Jewish landlord. The Aruch Hashulchan in 448:20 -  [סימן תמח - דין חמץ שעבר עליו הפסח, ודיני מכירת חמץ](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0357_L2) - seems to say it's irrelevant who the landlord is - one rents out the right to use the property.

> **כ**: ולאו דווקא מכירת החדר, דהוא הדין שישכיר לו החדר או המקום שהחמץ מונח בו, דשכירות קרקע גם כן נקנה בכסף, כמבואר שם. ובפרט א**ם המקום שהחמץ מונח בו אינו של הישראל, אלא שהוא אצלו בשכירות** – הרי אינו יכול למוכרו, אלא משכיר לו עם כל זכות ויפוי כח שיש לו.‏

See the Kitzur (ibid) that it's best to give the Chametz to the non-Jew. If that's not convenient, one doesn't have to rent out the entire apartment; renting the room where the Chametz is, is sufficient. Or - in case of need - one can divide up the room and rent out part of it (i.e. just the cupboard where the Chametz is in).

> וְאִם אִי אֶפְשָׁר שֶׁיִּקָחֵהוּ לְבֵיתוֹ, צָרִיךְ לְהַשְׂכִּיר לוֹ אֶת הַחֶדֶר שֶׁהֶחָמֵץ מֻנָּח בּוֹ
>
> אִם אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְהַשְׂכִּיר לוֹ כָּל הַחֶדֶר, מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהוּא צָרִיךְ גַּם כֵּן לְהִשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בּוֹ, יַעֲשֶׂה מְחִצָּה לִפְנֵי הֶחָמֵץ, וְיַשְׂכִּיר לוֹ אֶת הַמָּקוֹם שֶׁעַד הַמְּחִצָּה, וְיִכְתֹּב כֵּן בְּתוֹךְ הַשְּׁטָר. גַּם יִכְתֹּב שֶׁיֵּשׁ לְהַקּוֹנֶה דְּרִיסַת הָרֶגֶל לָלֶכֶת כִּרְצוֹנוֹ אֶל הַמָּקוֹם הַהוּא

Comment: +1 thank you, would be able to compile some more sources, so it can rounded out, instead of just being from the Kitzur. Shkoyach!

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv - I referenced the Aruch Hashulchan. The Shulchan Aruch doesn't discuss your questions, nor does the Kitzur Yalkut Yosef. That leaves me without any further sources.

Comment: I apologize I missed the Aruch Hashulchan (guess I need another coffee) and thank you for looking around so thoroughly. That satisfies me.